# Post Javascript Array to WebAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to post a Javascript Array to a WebAPI.

I have my Javascript Array like:

```
var checkedGroups = [];
var checkedStaff = [];

$.each(items, function () {

    if (this.checked) {
        type = dataAdapter.records[this.id - 1].VALUETYPE;
        if (type == 'Staff') {
            checkedStaff[checkedStaff.length] = this.value;
        } else {
            checkedGroups[checkedGroups.length] = this.value;
        }
    }
});
```

I am then sending this to my WebAPI using this:

```
data: { staff: JSON.stringify(checkedStaff) };
```

My WebAPI Controller is then like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] formData data)
{
    string string_group = String.Join(",", data.group);
    string string_staff = String.Join(",", data.staff); 
}
```

and my formData class is this:

```
public class formData
{
    public Array group { get; set; }
    public Array staff { get; set; }
}
```

As per above, I would like to split the array out to make a comma delimerated string.

But string_staff variable on the server side is just an empty string and my JSON data was this:

```
staff: "["1"]"
group: ""
```

I do not want to use key/value types in the array either.

Any idea's?

Comment: Maybe try changing your group and staff properties to `string[]` or `int[]` instead of `Array`.

Comment: Hi, yes I did have this as a string before I posted the question but not tried string[] will give it a go tomorrow

Comment: The way that WebAPI handles data binding is different than MVC. Try this `data: { '': myArray }` where myArray has one property for staff and one for group. Then make a ViewModel (that has two array properties, one for staff and one for group) then make this the incoming parameter type on your method.

Answer (score 0):

Change checkedGroups and checkedStaff variables to object literals. There's not really such a thing as an associative array in Javascript the way you're trying to set it.

```
var checkedGroups = {};
var checkedStaff = {};

$.each(items, function () {

    if (this.checked) {
        type = dataAdapter.records[this.id - 1].VALUETYPE;
        if (type == 'Staff') {
            checkedStaff[checkedStaff.length] = this.value;
        } else {
            checkedGroups[checkedGroups.length] = this.value;
        }
    }
});
```

You could keep them as arrays if you do:

```
checkedStaff.push(this.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use jQuery ajax function `$.ajax({ ... })` to post to WebAPI controller. I have found this method works the best:

```
function postJSON(data)
{
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/api/xyz',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" // must have this option set
  });
}

function doSomethingElse() {

  postJSON({ staff: checkedStaff, group: checkedGroup })
    .done(function(response) { ... });

}
```